# DataContext of view is always null

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, caliburn.micro

I'm trying to access the view model of a view in code-behind using the `DataContext` property. However, no matter at what point in the view lifecycle I'm trying to access it, the property is always `null`.

Simple dummy setup:

```
// shell
internal class ShellViewModel : Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.OneActive
{
    public ShellViewModel() {
        ActivateItem(new MyTestViewModel());
    }
}

// view code-behind
public partial class MyTestView : UserControl {

    public MyTestView() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnInitialized(EventArgs args) {
        var vm = DataContext as MyTestViewModel;
        Debug.Assert(vm != null); // is always null!
    }

}
```

The view get's correctly initialized, the view model is being called and both can be bound together. When I bind a property of the view model to a view control, it can be accessed without problems. Only during initialization, the `DataContext` of the view is always `null`. What do?

MVVM framework: Caliburn.Micro

Comment: can you try somewhere after the initialization,may be in Loaded event of the user control?

Comment: Check if `DataContext` is null first because you might be casting `DataContext` to the wrong type.

Comment: Where and how do you set your datacontext for the view ?

Comment: OnInitialized is too early. Do it later. Dunno what's recommended for caliburn, as I don't use it. Not sure why you're trying to manipulate the vm from codebehind... That's a code smell indicating what you're trying to do is likely wrong.  Last tip--you can use the Dispatcher to schedule execution later, such as after the application becomes idle, or after databinding happens.

Comment: @Will You were right, OnInitialized was way too early in the lifecycle which fixed it. Can you post this as an answer so I can accept it? Oh, and by the way, I don't manipulate the view model, I just need some data which the view model already provides for the 'view' and since the code-behind is just a 'code-part' of the 'view', I'm not doing anything else than what happens with databinding... just in code because I'm doing view-specific instrumentation not achieveable by markup. So no, I don't think that's a code smell. :)

Comment: Meh, I don't know *when* it should be done in the lifecycle.  If the current answer didn't hit it (Loaded event doesn't work) then just edit that and switch it to whatever event does work.  You can select that as correct to close this out.  It's fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public partial class MyTestView : UserControl {

  public MyTestView() {
    InitializeComponent();
  }
   
  public MyTestViewModel ViewModel() {
    return (MyTestViewModel)Datacontext;
  }
}
```

Doing this for whatever reason sort of breaks the idea behind the pattern since the viewmodel shouldn't be hardcoded into the view. Understandable for testing purposes but for any actual use; bad form.

--Edit -- I was thinking view only actions, but for some reason it was late and wasn't thinking about accessing data from within the view not accessing view from within ViewModel.

This should get what you need. Only after the Framework binds the view with the viewmodel (i.e. datacontext is set, once Loaded has been hit) will this work. If you need to do something beforehand I am not sure what else would be a better solution.

Comment: I don't really think accessing the view model from the view code-behind breaks the idea of MVVM since a) the code-behind is somewhat part of the view, b) the code-behind usually only targets the interface of the view model which the view already does by binding and c) it's only in code-behind since I need to instrument view-specific stuff not achieveable using only markup and for this, I need view model data, which is exactly also what happens with databinding. Or did I get something wrong here?

Comment: Almost all data I use will be a property from the viewmodel, I have yet run into a instance where I had to grab data from the data context in this nature.